# AJV JSON-Schema Validator with React not working

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm new to React World, currently trying to use AJV JSON-Schema Validator. When user upload Json file, I store it into state. Then after submitting I ran the validator. It's not working although in cosole.log it shows the data. Also if I hardcoded json into state like:

```
state = {
   file: {"foo": 2, "bar": 4}
}
```

Then it's working fine. My code:

```
import React from 'react';
let Ajv = require('ajv');
// import axios from 'axios';


class Form extends React.Component {

state = {
    file: '',
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.file)

    let ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true });
    //Validation Rule
    let validate = ajv.compile(
        {
            "properties": {
                "foo": { "type": "string" },
                "bar": { "type": "number", "maximum": 3 }
            }
        }
    );

    let valid = validate(this.state.file);

    if (valid) {
        console.log('Valid!');
    } else {
        console.log('Invalid: ' + ajv.errorsText(validate.errors));
    }
}

// Handle Upload Using FileReader
handleFile = (e) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let file = e.target.files[0];

    reader.onloadend = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.result);
        this.setState({
            file: event.target.result
        });
    }

    reader.readAsText(file)
}


render() {
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFile}/>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    )
  }
}
```

My Json Data :

```
{"foo": 2, "bar": 4}
```

Comment: Found The solution. I have to use JSON.parse() function.